# Is it normal that there is an MS-DOS FAT32 partition in the hd not made by me?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, efi

Digging on my slowness my EtreCheck report.. report a 'sound me strange' MS-DOS partition

```
Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662 disk0: (1 TB) (Rotational)
    [Show SMART report]
        EFI (disk0s1 - MS-DOS FAT32) <not mounted>  [EFI]: 210 MB 
        MacintoshHD (disk0s2 - Journaled HFS+) /  [Startup]: 999.35 GB (878.07 GB free)
        Recovery HD (disk0s3 - Journaled HFS+) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB
```

It is possible to know, maybe via terminal, when it was created and or from which process?

It could be that it has to do with an attempt to install bootcamp done time ago was not successful but then I formatted the disk so it is strange

Comment: hi klanomath not really duplicate but closely connected... is the right direction, I delete the question, thanks

Comment: There is no real reason to delete a question marked as duplicate!

Comment: redundancy of information for example?  But also it's not a 'exact duplicate'  some guys like me never heard EFI partition so do not solve doubts about an unknown MS-DOS partition

Comment: The linked question tells what is EFI, but is it expected to be a FAT32 partition, even in a mac system?